# How can I get nth item from array in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am building an array in SSJS, without knowing the key how can I get an item out of the collection with just the position number?

i.e. 2nd item in array.

Array Code:

```
var array = [];
array['1'] = "value1";
array['2'] = "value2";
array['a'] = "value3";
array['c'] = "value4";
array['d'] = "value5";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JonasLamberty is almost there.

He did not mention that what @DeploymentFailure (OP) is doing is not actually building an array.

The output of what OP was creating is: `[null, "value1", "value2", null, null]`.

This is because `array['1']` and `array['2']` are correctly placing the values into the rows accordingly. But it will completely ignore all other inputs using non-interger values. Which is why there are 5 rows, but only 2 non-null values.

That being said, his result does produce a positive result - but this is a false positive as it is actually displaying the THIRD value, not the second, because JS arrays begins with 0 as the first value, so technically 1 would be the second value in the array.

My solution would be to use `array.push('myvalue')` to push in the values in order or if you need them in specific spots, utilize the `array[n] = 'myValue'` but only with numeric chars.

If you need key/value pairs, you will need to utilize an Object, not an Array. This can be accomplished with something like `Obj.myKey = 'myVal'`.  You can create an array of objects though if you wish to utilize an array still to gather it by row.

To get the second key entry inside an object, it is not as easy as it is with an array. You will need to gather each of the keys via a for loop into an array and then use the array row number capability to get that and then use the `obj.key` ability to get that value.

See below for examples:

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core",1)

/* Array */

var array = [];
array.push("value1");
array.push("value2");
array.push("value3");
array.push("value4");
array.push("value5");
var variable = array[1];
Write(variable);
//Output: value2

/* Object */

var obj = {};
obj.a = "value1";
obj.b = "value2";
obj.c = "value3";
obj.d = "value4";
obj.e = "value5";

var keys = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    keys.push(key);
}

var secondKey = keys[1]

var variable = obj[secondKey];
Write(variable);
//Output: value2
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I am oversimplifying here- but I think all you need is this:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core",1)
var array = [];
array['1'] = "value1";
array['2'] = "value2";
array['a'] = "value3";
array['c'] = "value4";
array['d'] = "value5";
var variable = array[2];
Write(variable);
</script>
```

Result:
value2

Comment: Just a note, this only works because the array output is `[null, "value1", "value2", null, null]` because `array[1]` and `array[2]` are placing the values into according rows. but it completely ignores all other chars, meaning that all those values will be 'null'. If you need key/value pairs, you will need to utilize an Object, not an Array. You can create an array of objects though if you wish to utilize an array still. So in essence, this is actually displaying the THIRD value, not the second, because JS begins with 0 (first value), so technically 1 would be the second value in the array.