# Bulk delete rows from Data Extension using WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage, wsproxy

I am looking to delete rows from "ProxyTest22" data extension and trying to achieve this through WSProxy as the number of rows are in millions. I keep getting `Error executing delete call.\r\n  Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR\r\n - from OMMCommon --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'ProxyTest22' from assembly 'OMMCommon, Version=228.7.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3ca85e74a7e49d9'. - from mscorlib` error when running this in cloudpage.

I would really appreciate if someone can look into this script and advise.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
try{

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); 
var deCustKey = 'ProxyTest22'; //DE's CustomerKey
var moreData = true; 
var reqID = null; 

while(moreData) {

    var moreData = false;

    var deReturn = retrieveDERows(deCustKey,reqID);

    var moreData = deReturn.HasMoreRows;
    var reqID = deReturn.RequestID;
    var attributes = [];
    //Write("\n RequestID ********************* " + reqID);

    for (var a = 0; a < deReturn.Results.length; a++) {
        var results = deReturn.Results[a];

        for (var i = 0; i < results.Properties.length; i++) {

            var name =  results.Properties[i].Name;
            var value = results.Properties[i].Value;
            var object = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"' + name + '",Value:"' + value + '"}')
            //Write("\n Object Value " + object.Value);
            attributes.push(object);
        }
        
     }
     var deletedItems = prox.deleteBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", attributes);
      
    }

function retrieveDERows(deCustKey,reqID) {

    var cols = ["id"]; //DE Column Name to be retrieved

    if (reqID == null) {
        var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols); //executes the proxy call
    } else {
        desc = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", reqID);
    }

    return desc;
}
}catch (e) {
    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit and the rows were deleted. Took reference from [here](https://github.com/jdeblank/sfmc_dev/blob/master/wsproxy/DeleteBatch_filtered_DE_rows.js)

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
try{

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(); 
var deCustKey = '12345; //DE's CustomerKey
var moreData = true; 
var reqID = null; 

while(moreData) {

    var moreData = false;

    var deReturn = retrieveDERows(deCustKey,reqID);

    var moreData = deReturn.HasMoreRows;
    var reqID = deReturn.RequestID;
    var attributes = [];
    //Write("\n RequestID ********************* " + reqID);

    for (var a = 0; a < deReturn.Results.length; a++) {
        var results = deReturn.Results[a];

        for (var i = 0; i < results.Properties.length; i++) {

            var name =  results.Properties[i].Name;
            var value = results.Properties[i].Value;
           /* var object = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('{Name:"' + name + '",Value:"' + value + '"}')
            //Write("\n Object Value " + object.Value);*/
          
             attributes.push({
    CustomerKey: deCustKey,
    Keys: [{Name:"id", Value:value}]
  });
            
        }
        
     }
  Write(Stringify(attributes));
    var deletedItems = prox.deleteBatch("DataExtensionObject", attributes);
      Write("<br><br>" + Stringify(deletedItems));
    }

function retrieveDERows(deCustKey,reqID) {

    var cols = ["id"]; //DE Column Name to be retrieved
    
    if (reqID == null) {
        var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", cols); //executes the proxy call
        
    } else {
        desc = prox.getNextBatch("DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]", reqID);
    }

    return desc;
}
}catch (e) {
    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You @SwatiMishra. I am able to delete the DE rows that has only 1 Primary Key. 
 Getting error when deleting the rows with multiple(2 or more) Primary Key. Receiving ```ErrorMessage":"Cannot locate the existing record. Required keys are missing.``` error. 
  Probably would have to change the ```var attributes = [];``` to an Object <https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297133/how-can-i-get-nth-item-from-array-in-ssjs>  The DE Properties with two PK ```"Properties":[{"Name":"PrimaryKey1","Value":"xxxxxxx"},{ "Name":"PrimaryKey2","Value":"yyyyyyy"} ]```